# Spring Boot based webservices secured with Spring Security using client certificate authentication and custom RDN

Tags: authentication, spring-security, spring-boot, x509certificate, client-certificates

I need to create *webservices* that are secured by *client certificates* which my company provides for most employees. Because some employees don't have a certificate or sometimes our browser fails to access them the authentication should be "forgiving", that means at least a http status code 401 should be presented to the caller. As I am providing only webservices the employees will never enter a protected URL directly, the webservice will always be called by a webpage that could react to a 401 and display a friendly message.

I found out that I can have Spring Boot / the embedded Tomcat do the clientauth-part. For this I used an example from the web that does this:

```
connector.setAttribute("SSLEnabled", true);
connector.setAttribute("sslProtocol", "TLS");
connector.setAttribute("protocol",              "org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol");
connector.setAttribute("clientAuth", "want");
connector.setAttribute("keystoreFile", absoluteKeystoreFile);
connector.setAttribute("keystoreType", keystoreType);
connector.setAttribute("keystorePass", keystorePassword);
connector.setAttribute("keystoreAlias", keystoreAlias);
connector.setAttribute("keyPass", keystorePassword);
```

From what I learnt at least Spring Boot 1.2.1 makes all this easier so I will switch to using `server.ssl.client-auth=want/need` and the other parameters in application.properties soon.
My current setup uses code like this to retrieve the certificate and all this runs fine when called from my companies browser:

```
@RestController
public class WebGedoens {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home(HttpServletRequest request) {
        X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) request
                .getAttribute(JAVAX_SERVLET_REQUEST_X509_CERTIFICATE);
        if (certs != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < certs.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("Client Certificate [" + i + "] = "
                        + certs[i].toString());
            }
        }
...
}
```

The above dump showed me this subject DN:

```
Subject: CN=John Doe, EMAILADDRESS=john.doe_17@company.com, O=Company, C=DE
```

Because there are many "John Does" I need to get the EMAILADDRESS RDN from the subject DN because the email received an appended number that allows to identify each unique person.

How can I enable Spring Security for my method and tell Spring Security to take the certificate (there may be more than one) and extract the correct RDN ?